# Using .NET Minimal APIs, how should I return the contents of an AWS S3 object request response stream?

Tags: c#, performance, amazon-s3, .net-core, minimal-apis

I have an endpoint in my .NET 8 web api that I want to use to return 1 to 1 the contents of an S3 object which is a JSON file.

Using `AWSSDK.S3`, the request returns a response object with a stream to read the content. What would be the correct/most performant and memory efficient way to return that JSON file to my API's clients?

I have this so far:

```cs
app.MapGet("/timezones", async () =>
{
    var request = new GetObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("S3_BUCKET_NAME"),
        Key = "allData.json",

    };
    var response = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request);
    return Results.Stream(
        async (stream) =>
        {
            try
            {
                await response.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
            finally
            {
                response.Dispose();
            }
        },
        "application/json"
    );
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't return a redirect to a presigned link to the S3 object?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Results.Stream` accepting the stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results.stream?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-results-stream(system-io-stream-system-string-system-string-system-nullable((system-datetimeoffset))-microsoft-net-http-headers-entitytagheadervalue-system-boolean)):

```cs
app.MapGet("/timezones", async () =>
{
    // ...
    return Results.Stream(response, contentType: "application/json");
});
```

It automatically dispose the stream for you after serving the result ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0ea8814a654e17d581c51078645187e3104e0531/src/Http/Http.Results/src/FileStreamHttpResult.cs#L121)).

Or just perform redirect if the S3 object is accessible by the client (and you are ok with making the link public).